# Ansible to read data in a file and then use it

Tags: python, mysql, ansible

Is there a way using ansible i can read data from a text file and then use it in a sql query. The query i need to run is given below along with my text file contents. I know this can be done via python, but i need it in ansible, if anyone could help it would be great.

```
mysql query - UPDATE table SET password = "{}", salt = "{}" WHERE people_id IN (3,2);
```

my text file -

```
<password>
<salt>
```

I have done it using Python but cant figure out how to do it in ansible, i have done a lot of research but no solution.

```
import MySQLdb 
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","prajwalarora","password","database") 
cursor = db.cursor() 
file = open('/home/prajwalarora/Desktop/pass.txt','r') 
file_content = file.read() 
lines = file_content.split() 
file.close() 
query = 'UPDATE sc_people SET password = "{}", salt = "{}" WHERE people_id IN (3,2);'.format( lines[0], lines[1]) 
print query 
cursor.execute(query) 
db.commit() 
db.close()
```

i have been running queries (that dont require data to be read from a file) using this command in ansible

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DBNAME -e "source /home/prajwalarora/Desktop/file.sql"
```

file.sql contains queries that need to be run in **mysql cli**

Comment: you need to show us the text file with strings and exact query that you want to build. This is possible as in ansible you can easily use the `shell` module and other ansible modules to manipulate the file.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: @Zeitounator if you could answer my question, that would be great.

Comment: @PrajwalArora you can create a yml file if possible include that as vars using `include_vars: db_creds.yml` then replace the corresponding values using `{{ }}`. 
I assume creating a yml file is under your control.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar to the following

```yaml
vars:
  sql_text: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/prajwalarora/Desktop/file.sql') }}"

tasks:
  - name: Execute command
    command: mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DBNAME -e "{{ sql_text }}"
```